# Как правильно отобразить ресурсы, в каждом pictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, каким, не сложным способом можно управлять отображением ресурсов?

При наведении курсора на `pictureBox1` зеленый цвет должен поменяться на синий.

При отдалении курсора за пределы `pictureBox1` цвет должен стать прежним, зеленым.

При нажатии на `pictureBox1` цвет должен стать синим и не реагировать на отдаление курсора. При этом, в `panel1` отобразится форма `f1`. Все это должно отразится на других `pictureBox`.

Ресурсы, зеленый и синий для `pictureBox1`:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Green; //зеленый
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Blue; //синий
```

Код, который при нажатии на `pictureBox1` открывает форму внутри `panel1`

```
    private Form f1;
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.Controls.Clear();

        if (f1 == null)
        {
            f1 = new Form1();
            f1.TopLevel = false;
            f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(f1);
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Используйте события `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`.

Comment: Эти события и использую, только слишком много путаницы...

Answer (score 1):

Подписываете пикчабоксы на события:

```
pictureBox1.MouseEnter += PictureBoxes_MouseEnter;
pictureBox2.MouseEnter += PictureBoxes_MouseEnter;
pictureBox3.MouseEnter += PictureBoxes_MouseEnter;

pictureBox1.MouseLeave += PictureBoxes_MouseLeave;
pictureBox2.MouseLeave += PictureBoxes_MouseLeave;
pictureBox3.MouseLeave += PictureBoxes_MouseLeave;

pictureBox1.Click += PictureBoxes_Click;
pictureBox2.Click += PictureBoxes_Click;
pictureBox3.Click += PictureBoxes_Click;
```

Насколько я могу судить по вопросу, для всех `PictureBox` должно быть одинаковое поведение, поэтому используем для всех одни и те же методы.

Код обработчиков событий:

```
private void PictureBoxes_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    //pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Blue;
}

private void PictureBoxes_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Green;
    //pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Green;
}

private void PictureBoxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    //pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Blue;

    // отписываемся от событий
    pictureBox.MouseEnter -= PictureBoxes_MouseEnter;
    pictureBox.MouseLeave -= PictureBoxes_MouseLeave;

    // тут код работы с панелью
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вернусь попробую Ваш способ.

Comment: К сожалению, метод приводит к тому, с чем я все время сталкиваюсь. На `PictureBoxes_Click` не происходит фиксации ресурса `Resources.Blue`, потому, что `PictureBoxes_MouseLeave` не позволяет выйти курсору за пределы пикчабокса без смены ресурса на `Resources.Green`.

Comment: @Vitokhv - обновил ответ. Варианты могут быть разные. Это один из возможных способов.

Comment: Подскажите, почему `PictureBoxes` повторяется для всех `pictureBox 1,2,3`? Получается, что события это одно общее, или один общий тупик?

Comment: @Vitokhv - да, одно общее событие на все боксы. Чтобы не писать одинаковый код. Если это не подоходит - подписываем каждый пикчабокс на свой собственный обработчик события.

Comment: Слишком много путаницы... думаю привязать пикчабоксы к `RadioButton`, так хоть фиксация будет зависть от выбранного элемента.